# Laws of logarithms: why isn't $\frac{1}{4}\log_2(8x - 56)^{16 }- 12 = \log_2((8x-56)^{16})^{\frac 1 4} - 12$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This is a question about the application of the laws of logarithms.

Why isn't $\frac{1}{4}\log_2(8x - 56)^{16 }- 12 = \log_2((8x-56)^{16})^{\frac 1 4} - 12$ ?

According to the law of logarithms for powers, $\log_a p^n = n\log_a p$. I think I'm applying this rule correctly to the left member of the equation to obtain the right member. But when I evaluate the two expressions on my calculator, I get different results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be a problem with the way you put paranthesis

Comment: When you put a power 16 in the calculator I greatly suspect your calculator is first taking the log and then raising it to the power instead of the other way around. The calculator does not recognize that the 16 is on the (8x-56) before taking the log. This is what I notice with my TI. Same problem with trig functions and powers

Comment: What you have written here is correct. Something must be wrong with the way you are using the calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log_2 (8x-56)^{16}$ is ambiguous.  Do you mean $(\log_2 (8x-56))^{16}$,  or do you mean $\log_2\left( (8x-56)^{16}\right)$, i.e. is it the $16$'th power of the log, or is it the log of the $16$'th power?  It makes a big difference!
Your calculator is probably interpreting it as  $(\log_2 (8x-56))^{16}$.

Comment: It was a problem with the calculator's interpretation. Thanks.